# Can native react app code convert/rollback to native mobile code(ios and android)?

Tags: react-native

Basically the title says all - Can native react app code convert/rollback to native mobile code(ios and android)?

Background - there is a react native app and there are some bugs and I would like to export the react native code to their native app code (ios and android) which I can fix them in native apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The React Native JavaScript is never translated into Swift or Java code and then compiled - it runs within the Safari or Chrome JavaScript engines.  See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment) for more details.

However, as its name implies, React Native does rely on native code for more complex operations.  If the bugs are in those npm modules you might be able to fix them there.